# excell sheet editable from user list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a calendar of events. 
Some users can subscribe to those events and some events are paying.

I want to make a sort of excel sheet that I can edit online to have the list of the users that will be on the event and the user that already paid too.

I think the better way should be : add a field "payment" on the participation node, and the moderator could modify this value, but is it a way to show all te records into a sort of excel file ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you make you `event` node? do you using the built-in field module, or other modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To export excel file:** Since you have already used `Views` to display your events, you may try [Views Excel Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) module to export your data to an downloadable excel file.

**To import your modified excel file to Drupal:** I do not think it is easy to make the editing online, which means reflect your editing of excel file back to the drupal database. You need to upload the modified excel file and then need some work to write the change to database, which is not trivial and I am not aware of any existing modules supporting this.

**Recommended Solution:** From my understanding, what you want is to make the payment editing as easy as possible. If this is the case, you can add a `payment` field to `event` content type and expose the editing permission to moderators as you mentioned. Make this `payment` field invisible to normal users. To make your moderators easier to work, you can install modules like [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) to enable editing interface for all the involved events in one page, or make a custom module by yourself. In this way, you can get exactly what you want with excel file.

Comment: I have an event wich is not free. When someone pay (cash or via bank) the admin have to edit the payment to "ok" (true), online. The dya after the event, the admin have to print the registration list with statuses of paymens ;-)

I want to have an excell sheet as google docs where the client put the data of payment day after day

Comment: I still recommend you write your own module to provide an interface for the admin to update payment information for users. This should be more feasible than editing excel otherwhere and then import into your drupal website.

Comment: I will add a field payment that allow the admin to edit its value. Than after I will use a module to export datas (nodes of type event). Best way, no?

Comment: I have updated my original answer, please check if it is clear.